std::visit and parameter passing
I'm trying to use std::visit with the overload pattern. But I get an error when using the struct A by reference.
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

template<class... Ts>
struct overload : Ts...
{
  using Ts::operator()...;

  consteval void operator()(auto&) const
  {
    static_assert(false, "ERROR");
  }
};

template<typename T, typename...>
struct A {};

int main()
{
  const std::variant<int, bool, A<int>> v{true};

  std::visit(overload{
                 [](A<int> val) { /* works */ },
                 //[](A<int>& val) { /* does not work */ },
                 [](int val) { std::cout << val; },
                 [](bool val) { std::cout << std::boolalpha << val; },
             },
             v);
}

What's wrong here and how I could make it compile?
Edit:

error: static assertion failed: ERROR
11 |     static_assert(false, "ERROR");
|                   ^~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:61:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'overload<(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:28:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:30:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:31:18)>::operator()<const A>' requested here
56 |     { return std::forward<_Fn>(__f)(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
|              ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/invoke.h:96:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__invoke_impl<void, overload<(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:28:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:30:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:31:18)>, const A &>' requested here
91 |       return std::__invoke_impl<__type>(__tag{}, std::forward<_Callable>(__fn),
|                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/variant:1016:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__invoke<overload<(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:28:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:30:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:31:18)>, const A &>' requested here
1011 |           return std::__invoke(std::forward<_Visitor>(__visitor),
|                       ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/variant:1032:14: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__detail::__variant::__gen_vtable_implstd::__detail::__variant::_Multi_array<std::__detail::__variant::__deduce_visit_result<void ()(overload<(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:28:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:30:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:31:18)> &&, const std::variant<int, bool, A> &)>, std::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 2>>::__visit_invoke' requested here
1027 |                          decltype(__visit_invoke(std::declval<_Visitor>(),
|                                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/variant:968:48: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__detail::__variant::__gen_vtable_implstd::__detail::__variant::_Multi_array<std::__detail::__variant::__deduce_visit_result<void ()(overload<(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:28:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:30:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:31:18)> &&, const std::variant<int, bool, A> &)>, std::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 2>>::_S_apply' requested here
963 |                 std::index_sequence<__indices..., __index>>::_S_apply();
|                                                              ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/variant:947:7: note: (skipping 1 context in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
942 |             (_S_apply_single_alt<false, __var_indices>(
|              ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/variant:932:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__detail::__variant::__gen_vtable_implstd::__detail::__variant::_Multi_array<std::__detail::__variant::__deduce_visit_result<void ()(overload<(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:28:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:30:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:31:18)> &&, const std::variant<int, bool, A> &), 3>, std::integer_sequence>::_S_apply_all_alts<0UL, 1UL, 2UL>' requested here
927 |         _S_apply_all_alts(
|         ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/variant:1055:59: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__detail::__variant::__gen_vtable_implstd::__detail::__variant::_Multi_array<std::__detail::__variant::__deduce_visit_result<void ()(overload<(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:28:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:30:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:31:18)> &&, const std::variant<int, bool, A> &), 3>, std::integer_sequence>::_S_apply' requested here
1050 |         = __gen_vtable_impl<_Array_type, std::index_sequence<>>::_S_apply();
|                                                                  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/variant:1724:45: note: in instantiation of static data member 'std::__detail::__variant::__gen_vtablestd::__detail::__variant::__deduce_visit_result<void, overload<(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:28:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:30:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:31:18)> &&, const std::variant<int, bool, A> &>::_S_vtable' requested here
1719 |         _Result_type, _Visitor&&, _Variants&&...>::_S_vtable;
|                                                    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/variant:1761:18: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__do_visitstd::__detail::__variant::__deduce_visit_result<void, overload<(lambda at prog_joined.cpp:28:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:30:18), (lambda at prog_joined.cpp:31:18)>, const std::variant<int, bool, A> &>' requested here
1756 |             return std::__do_visit<_Tag>(
|                         ^
Line 22: Char 8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::visit<overload<(lambda at solution.cpp:28:18), (lambda at solution.cpp:30:18), (lambda at solution.cpp:31:18)>, const std::variant<int, bool, A> &>' requested here
22 |   std::visit(overload{
|        ^

Possible error on gcc 11.

what is the error ? Please post the code that has the error rather than code that needs to be modified to produce the error and please incldue the compielr error message in the question

Are you using Visual Studio (MSVC)? That's the only compiler I found that refuses the code as-is (and of course with the commented line uncommented as well). Not even with the proper [](const A<int>& val) will MSVC accept it.

You have a const variant and reference to non-const A. What is your expectation?

@TedLyngmo comment out A<int> and uncomment A<int>&, then you'll probably see it fail. Provided we're guessing the right error, because maybe OP meant sth else.

@alagner Yes of course. I just did it one at a time. MSVC doesn't accept any of it - not even if I make it [](const A<int>& val) - but that's because of static_assert(false I realized. It seems MSVC haven't implemented P2593 yet.

@alagner Currently I'm using whatever is the latest MSVC version on godbolt in /std:c++latest mode.

@TedLyngmo I'm using msvc

@Peter Then, you need an always_false trick. static_assert(false doesn't seem to play nice with MSVC yet.

okay, got it. I will do; thank you for you help

@Peter I added a version of the always_false trick in the link above. With that, MSVC accepts the code (given that you make it const A<int>&).

Raymond Chen blogged about the static_assert(false) issue: How can I create a type-dependent expression that is always false? and Of what use is a type-dependent expression that is always false?

const std::variant<int, bool, A<int>> // <—- Each variant is const. [const int, const bool and const A<int>]
Therefore the variants must be passed by either value or const lvalue reference.
But if the std::variant is non-const, the variants must be passed by either value or lvalue reference.
